# Adding additional files to Azure Build Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an Azure DevOps Pipeline which pulls from a repository and builds a Visual Studio web project. This is then published to an App Service.

I have several sensitive configuration files which are not included in the repository (or the VS project) and are stored as 'Secure Files' within the Azure DevOps system.

I need to include these files in the 'Config/Secure' folder for the package that gets published (within the zip file). I can download them, but no matter what I try, I cannot get these files to be included in the deployment zip file. They only appear in the 'drop' file system and thus I can't seem to deploy them to the Web App.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can do this? Thanks in advance and Pipeline YAML below:

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'AppSettings.secret.config'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'cache.secret.config'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'security.secret.config'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'Smtp.secret.config'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
    Contents: |
      AppSettings.secret.config
      cache.secret.config
      security.secret.config
      Smtp.secret.config
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/config/secret'
    OverWrite: true
    flattenFolders: true

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to include these files in the 'Config/Secure' folder for the package that gets published (within the zip file)

We can't add new files directly to the zip file. As a workaround, we could Extract the folder `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`, copy secure file to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PrescQIPPWebApp/config/secret` and zip the folder `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PrescQIPPWebApp`, then publish the Artifact.

In addition, since the zip file will not be deleted after extract, and the `PrescQIPPWebApp` folder also will not be deleted after archive, we need to add  `power shell` task to delete the zip file and `PrescQIPPWebApp` folder

I have updated your YAML build definition, you could try it and kindly share the result here.

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

#Extract PrescQIPPWebApp.zip file to $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PrescQIPPWebApp folder
- task: ExtractFiles@1
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PrescQIPPWebApp.zip'
    destinationFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PrescQIPPWebApp'
    cleanDestinationFolder: false
    overwriteExistingFiles: false

#Delete PrescQIPPWebApp.zip file
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Remove-Item ''$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PrescQIPPWebApp.zip'''

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'AppSettings.secret.config'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'cache.secret.config'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'security.secret.config'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'Smtp.secret.config'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
    Contents: |
      AppSettings.secret.config
      cache.secret.config
      security.secret.config
      Smtp.secret.config
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PrescQIPPWebApp/config/secret'
    OverWrite: true
    flattenFolders: true

#Archive file to PrescQIPPWebApp.zip
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PrescQIPPWebApp'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PrescQIPPWebApp.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

#Delete PrescQIPPWebApp folder
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Remove-Item -path ''$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PrescQIPPWebApp'' -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to amend the path on the 'ArchiveFiles@2' task as it was placing the files in the root of the zip and also change 'includeRootFolder' to false. But it works, thanks again - much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can download your secrect file into the destination you would like (pre-build). Just make sure that your project file has it included in the manifest. This works even if your file is git ignored and kept out of source control. Edit your project file and look for the content include section, then add your file there. In my case, it looks like this:

```
<Content Include="App_Data\secretfile.key" />
```

Then you dont have to unzip and rezip anything.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is configured to use them please move them into source control folder not ArtifactStagingDirectory

```yaml
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
    Contents: |
      AppSettings.secret.config
      cache.secret.config
      security.secret.config
      Smtp.secret.config
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/config/secret'
    OverWrite: true
    flattenFolders: true
```

So this is wrong because you move it directly to folder which you publish and VSBuild doesn't touch this folder at all.

And if you config folder in on root directory of your repo (and you use here only one repo), this should move your files into solution.

```yaml
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
    Contents: |
      AppSettings.secret.config
      cache.secret.config
      security.secret.config
      Smtp.secret.config
    TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/config/secret'
    OverWrite: true
    flattenFolders: true
```

But be aware, that publishing secret files (even as artifact) is not recommended approach. Please consider downloading them and putting into right place just before deploying.

Comment: Thank you Krzysztof, I have amended the target folder to use System.DefaultWorkingDirectory but the files are not appearing in the zip. You mention "if your project is configured to use them" - could you elaborate on that please as I'm probably missing something? Thanks again - really appreciate your help.